# Can I update the hosts inventory and use new hosts in same playbook?

Tags: ansible

I'm adding few hosts in the hosts inventory file through playbook. Now I'm using those newly added hosts in the same playbook. But those newly added hosts are not readble by the same playbook in the same run it seems, because I get -

```
skipping: no hosts matched
```

When I run it separately, i.e. I update hosts file through one playbook and use the updated hosts in it through another playbook, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're doing - but from what I gather, you're using the `add_host` module in a play.

It seems logical that you cannot limit that **same** play to those hosts, because they *don't exist yet*... so this can never work:

```
- name: Play - add a host
  hosts: new_host

  tasks:
    - name: add new host
      add_host: name=new_host
```

But you're free to add multiple plays to a single plabook file (which you also seem to have figured out):

```
- name: Play 1 - add a host
  hosts: a_single_host

  tasks:
    - name: add new host
      add_host: name=new_host

- name: Play 2 - do stuff
  hosts: new_host

  tasks:
    - name: do stuff
```

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to do something like this recently, using ansible 1.8.4. I found that `add_host` needs to use a group name, or the play will be skipped with "no hosts matched". At the same time I wanted play #2 to use facts discovered in play #1. Variables and facts normally remain scoped to each host, so this requires using the magic variables `hostvars` and `groups`.

Here's what I came up with. It works, but it's a bit ugly. I'd love to see a cleaner alternative.

```
# test.yml
#
# The name of the active CFN stack is provided on the command line,
# or is set in the environment variable AWS_STACK_NAME.
# Any host in the active CFN stack can tell us what we need to know.
# In real life the selection is random.
# For a simpler demo, just use the first one.
- hosts:
    tag_aws_cloudformation_stack-name_{{ stack
    |default(lookup('env','AWS_STACK_NAME')) }}[0]
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    # Get some facts about the instance.
    - action: ec2_facts
    # In real life we might have more facts from various sources.
    - set_fact: fubar='baz'
    # This could be any hostname.
    - set_fact: hostname_next='localhost'

    # It's too late for variables set in this play to affect host matching
    # in the next play, but we can add a new host to temporary inventory.
    # Use a well-known group name, so we can set the hosts for the next play.
    # It shouldn't matter if another playbook uses the same name,
    # because this entry is exclusive to the running playbook.
    - name: add new hostname to temporary inventory
      connection: local
      add_host: group=temp_inventory name='{{ hostname_next }}'

# Now proceed with the real work on the designated host.
- hosts: temp_inventory
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    # The host has changed, so the facts from play #1 are out of scope.
    # We can still get to them through hostvars, but it isn't easy.
    # In real life we don't know which host ran play #1,
    # so we have to check all of them.
    - set_fact:
        stack='{{ stack|default(lookup("env","AWS_STACK_NAME")) }}'
    - set_fact:
        group_name='{{ "tag_aws_cloudformation_stack-name_" + stack }}'
    - set_fact:
        fubar='{% for h in groups[group_name] %} {{
        hostvars[h]["fubar"]|default("") }} {% endfor %}'
    - set_fact:
        instance_id='{% for h in groups[group_name] %} {{
        hostvars[h]["ansible_ec2_instance_id"]|default("") }} {% endfor %}'
    # Trim extra leading and trailing whitespace.
    - set_fact: fubar='{{ fubar|replace(" ", "") }}'
    - set_fact: instance_id='{{ instance_id|replace(" ", "") }}'

    # Now we can use the variables instance_id and fubar.
    - debug: var='{{ fubar }}'
    - debug: var='{{ instance_id }}'

# end
```

Comment: Is there a way to extract "temp_inventory" into a variable? When I define it as a variable, host matching fails with  `skipping: no hosts matched`. When I keep it hard-coded, things work fine.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's by design or a bug. You could create a new question with your test case, and see if anyone else can answer. Post a link here and I'll be sure to take a look.

Comment: FYI these days I use terraform to provision, and ansible to configure. So there's no longer any need to modify the ansible inventory on the fly. Instead I'd either use the ec2.py inventory script, or run ansible-pull from a cloudinit userdata script.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are modifying the Ansible inventory *file* with your playbook, and then wanting to use the new contents of the file. Just modifying the contents of the file on disk, however, won't cause the inventory that Ansible is working with to be updated. The way Ansible works is that it reads that file (and any other inventory source you have) when it first begins and puts the host names it finds into memory. From then on it works only with the inventory that it has stored in memory, the stuff that existed when it first started running. It has no knowledge of any subsequent changes to the file.

But there are ways to do what you want! One option you could use is to add the new host into the inventory file, and *also* load it into memory using the add_host module. That's two separate steps: 1) add the new host to the file's inventory, and then 2) add the same new host to in-memory inventory using the [add_host module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/add_host_module.html):

```yaml
- name: add a host to in-memory inventory
  add_host:
    name: "{{ new_host_name }}"
    groups: "{{ group_name }}"
```

A second option is to tell Ansible to refresh the in-memory inventory from the file. But you have to explicitly tell it to do that. Using this option, you have two related steps: 1) add the new host to the file's inventory, like you already did, and then 2) use the [meta module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/meta_module.html):

```yaml
- name: Refresh inventory to ensure new instances exist in inventory
  meta: refresh_inventory
```